Hoeffding’s inequality
Is this True or False:
"For a hypothesis with a small in-sample error on a large dataset, Hoeffding’s inequality guarantees that the out-of-sample error will also be small with high probability."

Can you please formulate the title as a specific question? Also, we've asked your many times to put more effort into your posts. This post is very lazily written. This also looks like a homework problem and you should disclose that.

Strictly speaking Hoeffding’s inequality as a non-asymptotic probabilistic bound alone cannot guarantee this, you also need additional assumptions such as all in-samples are i.i.d. from their population and the said fixed hypothesis has to be independent of the in-sample data. Otherwise you would've never needed to consider the union bound for finite hypothesis class or infinite hypothesis class via its possible finite VC dimension to account for the worst-case selected hypothesis through empirical risk minimization out of the hypothesis class in PAC learning.
For a simple example, if you just select a perfectly over-fitted hypothesis from a fixed $N$ training data points such that the in-sample error is almost $0$, then the out-of-sample error cannot be guaranteed to be arbitrarily small as $\epsilon$ with arbitrarily high probability $\delta$ via any means including Hoeffding’s inequality.
